# 2D matrix java bluej

Tags: java, arrays, object, bluej

I am trying to create a matrix using a 2D array but in the matrix i want to put an object from another class in the array. I am getting a "incompatible types" error and I do not understand why. The matrix should look like this: 
| (1,2,3) (1,2,3) | 
| (3,2,1) (3,2,1) |

This is the constructor of the class I am creating the matrix.

```
public MatrixTriple2N(int n)
{
    this.n=n;
    int length=(int)Math.pow(2, n);
    //Triple[][] matrix = new Triple [length][length];
    MatrixTriple2N[][] matrix = new MatrixTriple2N [length][length]; //object array
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=new Triple(); //having the problem here
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code and contructor of the class i am trying to call inside the MatrixTriple2N class.

```
    public class Triple {

   private int a;
   private int b;
   private int c;


   public Triple() {
    a = b = c = 0;
   }

   public Triple(int p, int q, int r) {
    a = p;
    b = q;
    c = r;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume MatrixTriple2N is a matrix of objects of type `Triple`. Hence

```
MatrixTriple2N[][] matrix = new MatrixTriple2N[length][length];
```

is likely not what you are intending. I assume you like to crate s.th. like

```
Triple[][] matrix = new Triple[length][length];
```

now you can assign a new Triple to as an Element of that matrix.